# Algorithm for reducing 1D function to polyline with small number of points

Tags: python, algorithm, polyline, downsampling, decimation

### Problem

My input is 1D function `y = f(x)` and I want to find a way to approximate this function with a polyline with small number of points on some given interval `<x1, x2>`:

[image]

### What have I tried:

I solved this by making polyline with **many** points (1000+) and then decimating this polyline using [Ramer–Douglas–Peucker algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm).

[image]

So in (pseudo)python it would be something like:

```
def fn_to_low_poly(f, x1, x2):
    xs = numpy.linspace(x1, x2, 1000)
    ys = f(xs)
    return ramer_douglas_peucker_decimate(xs, ys, epsilon=0.001)
```

This works, but its too complicated and slow and I'm pretty sure there must be a better way.

I'm doing this in python/numpy/scipy now, but I may need to rewrite it in C or Rust or something else, so I don't care too much about specific way to solve this in python, I'd rather have a generic algorithm, although I'll be grateful for any help.

### Question:

Is there an algorithm for directly reducing 1d function (`float -> float`) to polyline with low number of points?

Comment: You're probably looking for the Graphics Gem paper *Adaptive Sampling of Parametric Curves*.  Let your search engine be your friend.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark that looks good - I knew what I wanted, but i didn't know what to search for. Thank you.